# Rails reCAPTCHA with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate a recaptcha into my website and I wanted to add some client side validation.

I chose to use [a gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) to include the recaptcha tags, but I wanted to trigger a function once the recaptcha is checked.

Looked through some google sites and found that a `data-callback` attribute with its value set to function name is all I need.

I used `recaptcha_tags` helper from the gem to set it up and then a jquery method to add this `data-callback` attribute as I have not seed an option to do this inside the gem.

```
$('.g-recaptcha').attr("data-callback", "myFunctionName");
```

After clicking the recaptcha the function is not called. Why?

Comment: did you check your javascript errors? make sure myFunctionName is available in the global scope.

Comment: That was the case! It was not in the global scope!

Answer (score 3):

I asume you have a form like this

## app/views/contacts/contact.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :nombre, :placeholder => I18n.t("contacto_formulario_nombre"),:required => true %>
  <%= f.text_field :apellido :placeholder => I18n.t("contacto_formulario_apellidos"), :required => true %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => I18n.t("contacto_formulario_email"), :required => true %>
  /** (....other tags ....) **/
  <%= recaptcha_tags :display => 'clean' %>
  <%= f.button I18n.t("contacto_formulario_continuar"), type: "submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

## app/assets/javascripts/contact.js

```
$(function() {
  $('.g-recaptcha').attr("data-callback", "recaptcha");
})
function recaptcha()
{
  console.log("captcha pulsado!");
  /** the actions you want, i.e. activate submit button **/
}
```

The magic ocurrs in the attribute "data-callback"

Hope it helps.

Marino

Comment: I like this solution. I use the callback to enable the submit button. The only problem is I don't know how to disable the button after the verification expired. I guess we need a different callback for that.

Comment: @Wit
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ambethia/recaptcha#recaptcha_tags
You're looking for  : `expired_callback`